# Distinct value for Two Column and Also the Third Column Value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, distinct-values

I have below Oracle table :-

```
**GROUP   VALUE   CODE    TYPE        USERID**
MALOY     A        B        3         198082
MALOY     A        B        3         198082
MALOY     B        A        2         198082
MALOY     B        A        2         198082
MALOY     C        D        1         198082
MALOY     C        D        1         198082
```

i want below answer, How i can achieve it.

```
**GROUP   VALUE   CODE    TYPE        USERID**
MALOY     A        B        3         198082
MALOY     B        A        2         198082
MALOY     C        D        1         198082
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP, VALUE, CODE, TYPE, USERID 
FROM your_table
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This one returning all distinct value

Comment: It will give output as per expected output in your question.

Comment: GROUP is a reserved word.  You should put it in double quotes.  It wouldn't be a bad idea to put VALUE and TYPE in double quotes as well they are also reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct * from your_table
```